# mysqli_sql_exception: Unknown column 'wp_' in 'field list' PHP 8

Tags: mysql

I cannot install latest wordpress at xampp[image]

Comment: Did you create a database first using phpmyadmin? if yes, is it named wordpress?

Comment: You should create a database, and then create a dedicated database user for the wordpress database. root should not be used.

Answer (score 0):

### If you are sure the db exists

I think the `wp-config.php`-File could not be created automatically (maybe for permission issues of either the wordpress-folder or the xmpp-process-owner).

Try the alternative installation from the first page before the db-credential-formular.